# Google Scripts / Sheets Add prefix to data once it has been entered into the cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Objectives**

1. Add a Prefix of CSC1[Leading Zeros] to a number such as 1291 or 12922 or 129223 this should apply to the whole column (Column F)
2. Ensure total string length is = 15 using padding of zeros so the cell value would be `CSC100000001291`
3. The user would only enter 1291 but I plan to make the script overwrite this to make the the cell value CSC100000001291

Can be done using a formula but across two columns but would prefer to use one column as it look tidier.

e.g [User Input]  = [Final Cell Value]

```
 - 1291 = CSC100000001291
 - 12922 = CSC100000012922
```

Currently trying to work this one out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

- An [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) to check when someone has updated a cell
- [`padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) to add the leading zeros
- [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the first 4 zeros with "CSC1" (since only the first occurrence will be replaced if passing a string instead of regular expression)
- [`setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) to update the edited cell

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart == 1) { // Column A
    const padded = e.value.padStart(15, 0);
    e.range.setValue(padded.replace('0000', 'CSC1'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can confirm this is exactly what was required, just had to tweak line 2 to my relevant column.

Comment: My understanding is that you set the cell to 15x zeros and then replace the first 4 digits to CSC1, but where does the the user input come in?

Comment: @unstacked55 I'm not sure I understand why you're asking that. From your question title "once it has been entered into the cell", the user input comes from the user editing a cell. Please help me understand what I'm misunderstanding here.

Comment: Hi Diego, yes I'm trying to understand the code a little more. Which part of the code references the user input?

Comment: @unstacked55 The user input is `e.value`. Take a look at the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) documentation, which describes the `e` being passed into `onEdit(e)`.

Comment: Thanks Diego, I thought that was the case.

Comment: I'm modifying this script so it adds 'ACT-' to the 6 digits entered in the cell, but getting an error, 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined'.  Do I need to specify a sheet name to run this one if I have multiple tabs?  My code is:

{code}
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart == 2) { // Column B to test with
    const padded = e.value.padStart(10, 'ACT-');
    e.range.setValue(padded);
  }
}
{code}

Comment: @user1509059 Please post a new question with the full details of what you're doing and how you're testing.