# Google Scripts / Sheets Add prefix international phone

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

thanks for your invaluable help.

I have a google form to which I would like to activate a script that automatically changes the telephone number entered by the customer.

Example (column G):
e.g [User Input] = [Final Cell Value]

```
3331231646 = +393331231646
3251022878 = +393251022878
```

I'm trying to solve this problem, can anyone help me?

thanks a lot

Comment: are we only adding the same country code to all numbers?

Comment: What have you tried and where is it failing?

Comment: @NaziA yes add the country code every time a customer signs up

Comment: Are you intending to use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) for this or just Google Sheets formulas?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Apps Script ;-)

Comment: @Diego I'm trying to follow this formula but it's different and I can't get it to work.
I'm not programming expert :-(
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64930993/google-scripts-sheets-add-prefix-to-data-once-it-has-been-entered-into-the-cel

Comment: @Monique G. Great, I just tried it and it works great! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Before proceeding to creating the script, add installable trigger first. See below steps on how to add triggers:

1.) In your Script Editor, go to **Edit** tab and click **Current project's triggers**
[image]

2.) Click **Add Trigger** in the lower right corner

[image]

3.) In the **Select event type** drop down, select **On form submit**
[image]

4.) If there's an authentication appears, just select your account and click **Allow**

5.) You will see these details after clicking **Save**
[image]

This is my sample script that can achieve this target:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var range = e.range;
    var responseArray = e.values;
    var countryCode = "+39";

    //For this part, you just need to change the index[] to the specific column of mobile number in your spreadsheet, count starting from 0, equivalent to column A. 
    //In my sample, the column of mobile number on my spreadsheet is at column G, so the index I indicated was 6.
    responseArray[6] = countryCode + e.values[6]; 
    //A Range object is representing the cell or range of cells that were last added/inputted in the spreadsheet from the form.
    range.setValues([responseArray]);
}
```

See sample output below:

[image]